# Java command on Eclipse OpenMPI

Tags: java, eclipse, command, mpi, openmpi

Just started playing with OpenMPI. I run my first app (Hello.java), on the terminal, successfully in this way:

`mpirun -np 4 java Hello`

How can I run this command on Eclipse?

Thanks